# WPF: How to assign IsMouseOver and IsPressed Button State backgrounds from Code Behind no XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some runtime generated WPF buttons that I need to style using code behind. I have the Style below in a code behind variable (            Style Editstyle = Application.Current.Resources[x] as Style;)

How would I change the DynamicResource of the values in the Trigger section from codebehind?
Like **style.Trigger.IsFocused.Background = bitmapX;**
Also style.Key="NewStyleCopy1";

```
    <Style x:Key="INIT_A" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource back}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource fore}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border"
                                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource stroke}"
                                                BorderThickness="1"
                                                Padding="4,2"
                                                CornerRadius="0"
                                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource altback}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource altfore}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource altstroke}" />
                            <Setter Property="Button.Effect" Value="{DynamicResource a_hbtnglow}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource altback}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource altfore}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource altstroke}" />
                            <Setter Property="Button.Effect" Value="{DynamicResource a_hbtnglow}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource altback}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource altfore}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource altstroke}" />
                            <Setter Property="Button.Effect" Value="{DynamicResource a_hbtnglow}" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense. The `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed` states are set in response to GUI events, and your code should be reacting to these via the usual data-binding mechanisms, I can't think of any reason at all why you'd want to "set" them yourself. Also, the fact that you're trying to do this in code-behind is a big red flag, after 15+ years of WPF development I've never once seen a case where runtime-generated controls had to be created in code-behind. It'll be a lot easier for people to help you if explain exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a UI that is user customizable. At run time an image can be chosen to make a Brush for a Button control (and there can be many Buttons customized this way). I would like to be able to set 3 image states for the button (Static Background, IsMouseOver and IsPressed). Using btn.Background i can set the background. But not the other parameters that I need. Is it possible to copy a Style with a new name at run time and change it's brush assignments? I hope this clarifies further.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done in XAML by defining a `Trigger` for each state:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can make use of the `Style.BasedOn` property to extend a particular `Style`, for example a default `Style` for all `Button` elements. This way you can create a more specific `Style` that includes all attributes of the base `Style`:

```xml
<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="GeneratedButtonsStyle" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
       TargetType="Button">

  <!-- Override the base Style value -->
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />

  <!-- Extend the base Style -->
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Bionic Code, this is an epiphany here. Ok, Using your concept, Let's say I have 10 dynamically generated buttons. I'd like to make 10 of these 'Based on' type styles with unique names and colors for the trigger Ispressed foreground and assign them to these ten buttons. What approach should one use? Basically I'm trying to create custom styles on the fly with specific parameters for the trigger properties and the name of the style and assign it to it's button.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the style and edited the properties.
I appreciate all your suggestions.

```
            var xu = styleCopy("ButtonAA");
            Trigger t = new Trigger();
            t.Property = Button.IsMouseOverProperty;
            t.Value = true;
            Setter setter = new Setter();
            setter.Property = Button.BackgroundProperty;
            setter.Value = Brushes.Blue;
            t.Setters.Add(setter);
            xu.Triggers.Add(t);
            btn.Style = xu;
```